Requests from Docker php/nginx container timeout
I have app that crawls data from a marketplace. It runs on docker. Compose.yml file content is as follows.
version: '3'

networks:
    nginx-php82-mysql8:

services:
    # nginx
    nginx-service:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx-container
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php82-service
            - mysql8-service
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8

    php82-service:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
        container_name: php82-container
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8

    mysql8-service:
        image: mysql:8
        container_name: mysql8-container
        ports:
            - "4306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        command: --mysql-native-password=ON --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        restart: always # always restart unless stopped manually
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8

    mailer-service:
        container_name: mailer-container
        restart: on-failure:10
        image: schickling/mailcatcher
        environment:
            - RAILS_ENV=development
        ports:
            - "1080:1080"
            - "1025:1025"   
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8

    rabbitmq3-service:
        container_name: rabbitmq3-container
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
        ports:
            - '5672:5672'
            - '15672:15672'
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8

    redis-service:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        container_name: redis-container
        networks:
            - nginx-php82-mysql8
        

App gets product data from the marketplace, then dispatches messages for each product (to get reviews, offers etc.). It works as expected in the start, but after consuming around 30k (5-6 hours) messages I keep getting TimeoutException ("Idle timeout reached for URL").
Using Symfony Http client for making requests. First I thought the issue must be related to Http client, but noticed that I cannot even do composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.0, it also times out.
What might be the reason for timing out?
To fix this I have to rebuild all containers. And it starts to work well again, then fails with the same TimeoutException after some hours of work. Simple docker compose down and docker compose up does not help.

Are you able to manually connect to the affected resources e.g. via a command line interface or client? Try adding a healthcheck on each service in the docker compose file and check whether they are still healthy when this happens. Each service may require a different kind of healthcheck

@apokryfos yes I am able to make postman requests manually. Will try that, and comment what happened. Thank you for suggestion

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have run command couple times more. It worked more than a day without any timeouts. Going to need to run the command again later, will see how it goes. For now it is not clear why it was timing out
